# OneDrive in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive

I'm trying to load file to OneDrive

```
using (Stream contentStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
      var uploadedItem = await _client.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("Orange Reminder/" + file.Name).Content.Request().PutAsync<Item>(contentStream);                                                
}
```

And I have error: invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
What's wrong?

Comment: The code you've posted is right. What's the `file.Name` you are using? Maybe the `file.Name` is not valid.

Comment: Reminders.json and I'm trying ItemWithPath("Orange Reminder/Reminders.json") so, too, does not work

Comment: I tested with `ItemWithPath("Orange Reminder/Reminders.json")`, it also works well in my side. Could you please share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?